# Forcing file migration after deleting field

Tags: files, migrations

I have a situation where I am working on Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 migration.  The migration is being done in stages, and stage one is now live.

I am working on stage 2, and have run into a snag file file migrations.

We had a content type 'foo' with field 'field_bar'.  It was originally created as File, but should have been image.  We ran migrations, and everything went OK (all files were part of original migration).

'foo.field_bar' got deleted and recreated as Image.  When we re-run migrations, the files aren't being attached.

As far as I can tell, is that the source/destination pair exists in `{migrate_map_files}` but the `fid` doesn't exist in `{file_managed}`, more than likely because it got deleted during garbage collection when cron ran.

What is the best option to force these migrations to run again?  Is there a way to do this with the Migration classes, or should I delete the bad rows from `{migrate_map_files}`?

Comment: how did you rerun the migrations?

Comment: Reset the watermark in {migrate_status} and then `drush mi files`.  It says it updated all of the files, but there are still orphaned sources w/ no corresponding entry in `{file_managed}`.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to use a query, and manually cleanup the `{migrate_map_files}` table

```
$fids = db_query('
  SELECT mmf.sourceid1 FROM {migrate_map_files} mmf
  LEFT JOIN {file_managed} f ON f.fid = mmf.destid1
  WHERE f.fid IS NULL
')->fetchCol();

db_delete('migrate_map_files')
  ->condition('sourceid1', $fids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

reset the watermark in `{migrate_status}` and then re-run my files migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can set the needs_update column to 1 for all the known entities that have this issue, if you do this and run the migration with `drush migrate-import MyMigration --needs-update`. The other way would be to force update all items: `drush migrate-import --update MyMigration`

Comment: When I do this the migration runs, it says that the files have been updated, but the corresponding entry in `{file_managed}` still doesn't exist.